# Substances in WADA's monitoring program high risk?

Tags: doping

Caffeine was earlier prohibited but now in the monitoring program. As of 2016, the [list](http://list.wada-ama.org/list/s6-stimulants/) contains

> *"Bupropion, caffeine, nicotine, phenylephrine, phenylpropanolamine, pipradol and synephrine: These substances are included in the 2016 Monitoring Program, and are not considered Prohibited Substances."*

What does it mean to be under monitoring? Can I drink coffee before competitions under WADA's supervision or use synephere stimulants?

Comment: As it refers to the definition and applicability of part of a regulation covering sporting competitions, this question is not asking for health or medical advice. It is therefore *not off-topic*.

Answer (score -3):

USADA does pretty good job in explaining [here](http://www.usada.org/substances/prohibited-list/athlete-guide/). There is always a risk that you need to manage and reduce the potential health problems.

1. [High Risk List](http://www.usada.org/substances/supplement-411/), [reduce risk](http://www.usada.org/substances/supplement-411/reduce-risk-testing-positive-experiencing-adverse-health-effects/) and [Supplement411.org](http://Supplement411.org)
2. [USADA](http://www.usada.org/substances/tue/determine/) contact
3. [Determine If You Need a Therapeutic Use Exemption (TUE)](http://www.usada.org/substances/tue/determine/)

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please quote the relevant material or statements from your sources, to avoid linkrot and to ensure the answer is self-contained.